# Magento2: How to add Paypal checkout and Paypal credit button on custom .phtml file?

Tags: magento2, custom, paypal, cms-pages

How to add the Paypal checkout and Paypal credit button in the custom .phtml file?

I want to add the same as a mini cart/my cart PayPal button on the custom page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Created a link in .phtml file for Paypal Express:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
$paypalexpress = $baseurl.'paypal/express/start/button/1/';

<div id="button">
    <a href="<?php echo $paypalexpress; ?>">
    <img id="btnPayPal" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add the same as mini cart/my cart PayPal button on the custom page. Thanks